# Distribution of square numbers in intervale

Tags: approximation

The square numbers are of the form $n^{2}$ $(1,4,9,16,...)$

My question is there some formula to know how many square numbers up to $x$? or a  least approximation formula ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  There are approximately $\sqrt x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Why how you get this bound what about the error term.?is there a better approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n^2\le x<(n+1)^2$, then $n\le \sqrt x\lt n+1$, which means $n=\lfloor\sqrt x \rfloor$,

where $\lfloor y\rfloor$ is the [greatest integer part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $y$.